# Flex 4.5 Not listening to custom event dispatched in custom AS class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events

I have the following situation:

I have an event handler, that displays small messages in my application's statusbar.
These messages get passes through by dispatching events from custom components.
A simple message could be like "HTTP Error" or so.

Now, the main event listener, in the main application file, listens to the event dispatched by any custom component, but seems to refuse listening to events dispatched by custom AS classes.

Here is my code for the custom event:

```
package main.events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ShowNoticeEvent extends Event
    {
        public var message:String;
        public static const SHOW_NOTICE:String = "showNotice";

        public function ShowNoticeEvent(type:String, msg:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this.message = msg;
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new ShowNoticeEvent(type, message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the event listener in the main application file:

```
addEventListener(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, showNoticeListener, true);
```

And this is the custom AS class that dispatches the custom event. I pasted all the code, so you could see the whole part of it.

```
   package components.dashboard
{
    import components.dashboard.models.*;

    /* Event imports */
    import flash.events.*;
    import main.events.*;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

    [Event(name="showNotice", type="main.events.ShowNoticeEvent")]
    public class Controller extends UIComponent
    {
        private var baseUrl:String;

        public function Controller(baseUrl:String)
        {
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        }

        public function getRunningQuotations():void
        {
            var runningQuotationsList:RunningQuotationsList = RunningQuotationsList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=1", runningQuotationsList.updateList, "pnlRunningQuotations"); 
        }

        public function getRecentProjects():void
        {
            var recentProjectsList:RecentProjectsList = RecentProjectsList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=2", recentProjectsList.updateList, "pnlRecentProjects");
        }

        public function getLatestCustomers():void
        {
            var latestCustomersList:LatestCustomersList = LatestCustomersList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=3", latestCustomersList.updateList, "pnlLatestCustomers");
        }

        private function execService(url:String, listener:Function, component:String):void
        {
            var basicService:HTTPService = new HTTPService(baseUrl);
            basicService.showBusyCursor = true;
            basicService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, function(e:FaultEvent):void{httpFault(e, component)});
            basicService.method = "POST";
            basicService.resultFormat = "text";
            basicService.url = url;
            basicService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, listener);
            basicService.send();            
        }

        private function httpFault(event:FaultEvent, component:String = null):void {
            var faultstring:String = event.fault.faultString;
            var eventObj:ShowNoticeEvent = new ShowNoticeEvent(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, faultstring, true); 

            dispatchEvent(eventObj);
            trace(faultstring);
        }
    }
}
```

So to sum it all up:
- The event listener listens to the custom event dispatched by any custom component.
- The event listener does not listen to the custom event duspatched by an AS class.

Those who wonder, the event really gets dispatched, that's why I added a trace call.

Comment: Is your question "Why isn't my event handler executing code?"  Or something else?  Have you added the Controller class as a child to some container that is on the displayList?  If not; the events won't bubble.

Comment: Yes and no, the event handler only executes the code when the event is dispatched from within a child component, but not when it is dispatched from within an AS class. The controller class isn't a child of some container from the displayList, so it won't bubble. I don't think I can make it a child, or, I could in this case, but then I couldn't do that with my models, they aren't childs from anything I guess?

Comment: You should look at Robotlegs for a better way of handling communication among your Classes. A Controller Class should not be a View (which any Class extending UIComponent is), and so it should not be able to dispatch events against the display list itself.  Not to mention that this is a Service Class, not a Controller Class at all. You might want to spend some time at http://www.AS3DP.com to get a feel for how to use design patterns to accomplish your goals, and not tightly couple your code by using Singletons http://tinyurl.com/4qq53yj

Comment: I only made this extend UIComponent, because I wasn't able to dispatch events, only when I extended that class. And yes, I know about the fact that this is actually more a model/service class, then a controller class, I'm working on putting all mxml AS code in a controller class, and putting the currentcontroller code in models. I don't see any singletons in my code atm? But I'll read your docs provided, thanks.

Comment: You can extend EventDispatcher to be able to dispatch events (or implement IEventDispatcher). In your code, RecentProjectsList.getInstance() stinks to high heaven like a Singleton.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Ok Amy, but your giving answers to questions not asked. I just want to know how to be able to listen to events thrown in classes wich aren't part of the stage...

Comment: Extend EventDispatcher not UIComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of Controller Class would have to be added to stage for that to work.

by doing

```
addEventListener(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, showNoticeListener, true);
```

in the main file you are adding the listener to the stage.

So basically you are doing.

```
stage.addEventListener(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, showNoticeListener, true);
```

If controler instance is not on stage you won't see the event.

You might want to look into a Singleton type pattern for your data management as that would fit this setup pretty good.

Comment: stage.dispatchEvent just gives my a null reference... 
How would I use that singleton type pattern? I know what it is, but I just can't seem to see the use of it in this case, could you put me on the right track?

Comment: Singletons have no acceptable use case http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Comment: @mortana You turn Controller class into a singleton. Basically you only have one global instance of the class. You can attach all your listeners to that.

Comment: @Amy contrary to that review the issue of this question is geared towards global events and that is perfect for a singleton.

Comment: Yes, a lower case singleton (only one in the program, such as a RobotLegs Event bus), but not a Singleton with a capital S (global state accessible from everywhere via a static property). Global State is a quick road to an unmaintainable mess that you won't be able to rewrite once you realize how horrible a mess you've gotten yourself into. Google even has a Singleton detector to find them and ferret them out.

Comment: @The_asMan, but then I would have to make every AS class I have a singleton, and this just doesn't seem right, right? I'm thinking of passing the stage (or parentApplication) to any AS class constructor, and using that one to dispatch events from within AS classes, but this also seems a temp solution ...

Comment: @Mortana no you just make the one class holding the data you need a Singleton.

Comment: @The_asMan, but I have multiple AS classes that fire events that should be catched in main.mxml?

Comment: @Mortana A singleton is a single entry/exit point. In your case it would be for dispatching events and listening for events on your multiple classes. I would suggest you do some research on design patterns and figure out the best route for you to go.

Comment: I made an "Event Wrapper" per component. This is a singleton, that takes care of dispatching all events this component dispatches. I then connect it in my main application, for listening to events. This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Main:

```
Controller.getLastInstance().addEventListener(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, showNoticeListener, true)
```

.

```
package components.dashboard
{
    import components.dashboard.models.*;

    /* Event imports */
    import flash.events.*;
    import main.events.*;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

    [Event(name="showNotice", type="main.events.ShowNoticeEvent")]
    public class Controller extends UIComponent
    {
        static public function getLastInstance():Controller { return _instance; }
        static private var _instance:Controller;
        private var baseUrl:String;

        public function Controller(baseUrl:String)
        {
            _instance = this;
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        }

        public function getRunningQuotations():void
        {
            var runningQuotationsList:RunningQuotationsList = RunningQuotationsList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=1", runningQuotationsList.updateList, "pnlRunningQuotations"); 
        }

        public function getRecentProjects():void
        {
            var recentProjectsList:RecentProjectsList = RecentProjectsList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=2", recentProjectsList.updateList, "pnlRecentProjects");
        }

        public function getLatestCustomers():void
        {
            var latestCustomersList:LatestCustomersList = LatestCustomersList.getInstance();

            execService("index.php?a=3", latestCustomersList.updateList, "pnlLatestCustomers");
        }

        private function execService(url:String, listener:Function, component:String):void
        {
            var basicService:HTTPService = new HTTPService(baseUrl);
            basicService.showBusyCursor = true;
            basicService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, function(e:FaultEvent):void{httpFault(e, component)});
            basicService.method = "POST";
            basicService.resultFormat = "text";
            basicService.url = url;
            basicService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, listener);
            basicService.send();            
        }

        private function httpFault(event:FaultEvent, component:String = null):void {
            var faultstring:String = event.fault.faultString;
            var eventObj:ShowNoticeEvent = new ShowNoticeEvent(ShowNoticeEvent.SHOW_NOTICE, faultstring, true); 

            dispatchEvent(eventObj);
            trace(faultstring);
        }
    }
}
```

Not Ideal since you could only ever have 1 of them.
But I think better than having to turn a simple EventDispatcher into DisplayObject and add it to stage just to Simply bubble.

Comment: This wouldn't be a beauty solution for sure, since then I have to do this for every AS class I have?